# new to java Declaration

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn the java declaration, this what I have so far:

1. Access modifiers can be private, public and protected. So private can only be accessed within the declared class itself? Public  allows anyone to have access to it and protected is when other subclass are allow access to it. I'm right so far?
2. Next is Types they are as follows (int, bytes, double and char). I don't understand how char is used so that would be nice if someone could explain that to me.

The bit I'm getting stuck on is Name (reference) what is this and how is it used? I'm bit confused about this.

Comment: Do you know any other programming language? C, C++, Python any other? Have a look at this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: google would have taken less time answering it than posting question here. Make some efforts!!

Comment: [char](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/24.html)

Comment: How do you learn? I find it very uncommon to start with the access modifiers... You have to understand concepts like variables and expressions first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should get a beginners book or some tutorial.
Look at this link later:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

About access modifiers(question 1):

- Private: methods and or fields(variables) are only visible to the class. If i instantiate it, i can't access them.
- Protected: methods and or fields are visible to the package in wich the class is contained and to all subclases of this class.
- Public: methods and or fields are visible to everyone

About types(question 2):
You should really google this a bit or go to the link i mentioned.
Never the less, you can read about chars here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm.
In Java there are two types of types, BuiltIn types and "Object types";

BuiltIns ---> basically they are not objects. they do not have methods.
would kind of be like the types in C.

- int
- char
- double
- float
- byte

NOTE THEY ALL START WITH LOWERCASE

"Object Types" ---> the are objects. they have methods. (google for more info)

- Integer
- Char
- Double
- Float
- Byte

NOTE THEY ALL START WITH UPPERCASE--->differentiates them from builtins

BUILT IN TO OBJECT AND VICE VERSA

Somewhere along the way you'll read something called auto boxing and unboxing. Basically, java can change from one type to the other without you having to worry about conversion(most of the time). 
The easiest way to see it is in code:

```
Integer objInt = 3    //object integer 
int normalInt = 2     //built in int
objInt = normalInt    // auto boxing of normalInt and assign to objInt
objInt += 5           // objInt = 7
normalInt = objInt    // auto unboxing of objInt to builtin
```

About references(question 3):

Google a bit....http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

a reference variable would be "objInt" from the example above. Note it is an object, and objInt is a variable that "points" to the obj. Whats inside de variable is the "reference".
Another example:

```
Person prsn = new Person();  //prsn references the obj Person that was created
prsn.sayHi();   //just calling some method from the obj referenced by prsn
```

COMMENT:

Not sure if you deserve getting down voted for the question because you trying to understand. But you should google a bit before posting.

Best of lucks :)

Comment: thanks you so much nachocifu, i'm dyslexic so reading stuff from google sometimes confuses me even more, and i just need someone to brake it down bit more for me, but you broke it down nice so thank you for that. sorry if i upset or made anyone mad because of my post.